# How can I make a SQL connection using Encrypt with TrustServerCertificate in SQL connection string?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server that has a private SSL certificate.

I have set `TrustServerCertificate` to `True`, but `Encrypt` is set to `False`, and when I try to connect, I get this error :

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient  Provider)

Do I need to have both set to True? Do they work together either both True or both False?

Comment: Yes. You need encrypt set to true. Is this a preproduction environment? (I hope so)

Comment: yes pre production.

Comment: Why is encrypt required to be set to true , cant trust be true and encrypt to false. Where is it documented that they need to be the same ?

Comment: Do you explicitly set `Encrypt=False` in your connection string? Because the default setting changed from `False` to `True` last year in [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228), [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754) and [OLEDB Driver 19.0 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/ole-db-driver-19-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3170362).

Comment: And even earlier than that for [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-general-availability-of-microsoft-data-sqlclient-4-0/ba-p/2983346).

Comment: `Encryption=False` is ignored when `TrustServerCertificate=True` btw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate

Comment: What do you mean by "_**private** SSL certificate_", exactly? Do you mean a self-signed certificate - or an internal PKI-issued (not self-signed) certificate? (Also note that "SSL" is old terminology: SSL 3.0 was replaced by TLS 1.0 in 1999). Is there a reason you can't explicitly/manually mark the self-signed certificate (on the client) as a trusted cert, or use a PKI/CA with a redistributable cert?

Comment: a self-signed certificate

Comment: @Dai "If `TrustServerCertificate` is set to `true` **and encryption is turned on**, the encryption level specified on the server will be used even if `Encrypt` is set to `false`. **The connection will fail otherwise**."  One of the worst documentation sentences ever https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @PaulMaxwell If there's a competition for harrowing official docs then it [could always be worse...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.html)